# Set an object to Immutable Map of key value (value is an array or list) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, object, set, immutable.js

I have an object (myObj) which I want to set it to an Immutable Map that has key value shape and value is a list or an array.

```
 const myObj = {
                "a": 1,
                "b": 2,
            };
```

now I want to set this object into:

```
const x = Immutable.Map({
"content": []
})
```

how can I get the blow result?

```
{"content": [
    {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2,
    }
  ]
}
```

I have already tried : myObj = myObj.set("content", x) but this would not make the content value as an array.

Comment: myObj is simple object not `Map`, also `Map` need values in form of `[key, value]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` expects `[[K, V]]` structure for adding values, also `myObj.set("content", x)` is right as `myObj` is not `Map` it's just simple object

```js
const myObj = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
};

const x = Immutable.Map([["content",[myObj]]])

console.log(x)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```